# Setting custom normals without customdata_custom_splitnormals_add() operator?

Tags: python, scripting, normals

I'm trying to make my scripts more low-level and less operator-dependent. One thing that I haven't been able to figure out is this one:

```
me.use_auto_smooth = True
bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_add()
me.normals_split_custom_set(no_array)
```

Is there any way to do it without the operator? If so, what's the corresponding low-level code?

Comment: do you actually want to use custom_split_normals?
i'm using it like this: https://github.com/Aadjou/blender-scripts/blob/master/utils_split_normals.py

Comment: Yup, I want to set them on a model that had none before. I always thought I first have to create the data layers as from the GUI, hence the operator customdata_custom_splitnormals_add(). Will try your code!

Comment: i was mostly wondering what you want to do with the split normals, because it's super badly supported by blender and you are not able to work with your data much more, i'd avoid it unless you are writing an exporter, in that case you can have a look at this example / line:
https://github.com/archilogic-com/data3d-blender-io/blob/a5de9ae9ec7b25f00496d8ca120cabec877709f2/io_scene_data3d/export_data3d.py#L230

Comment: Indeed, it is for an importer / exporter combination. The thing is, with the current blender, it seems to work without the operator and even without me.calc_normals_split(). I'm not sure why, but I remember it was not working without the operator in 2.70-ish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you don't need the operator at all and I was getting funky results because I had a remove_doubles operation further down the pipeline.

Working example code:

```
no_array = []
for face in me.polygons:
    for vertex_index in face.vertices:
        no_array.append(mesh_verts[vertex_index][3:6])
    face.use_smooth = True
if use_custom_normals:
    me.use_auto_smooth = True
    me.normals_split_custom_set(no_array)
```